# Why my views start animation in the same time?

Tags: android, animation

I want my views appearing gradually. So I use Timer to delay the time the views appear. However it do not work. Strangely, the views appear in the same time!
Here's my code.

```
public static void startAnimations(final View... views) {
        //assume 720
        int screenWidth = 720;
        final TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(-screenWidth / 2, 0, 0, 0);
        final AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.5f, 1);
        translateAnimation.setDuration(800);
        alphaAnimation.setDuration(800);

        mViewIndex = 0;
        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (mViewIndex >= views.length) {
                    timer.cancel();
                    mViewIndex = 0;
                    return;
                }
                View view = views[mViewIndex];
                final AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);
                animationSet.setDuration(800);
                animationSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                animationSet.addAnimation(alphaAnimation);
                animationSet.addAnimation(translateAnimation);
                view.startAnimation(animationSet);
                mViewIndex++;
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0x11);
            }
        }, 0, 300);
    }
```

Comment: try increasing duration value.

Comment: I think your image is missing.

Comment: @Rustam so...is it impossible that more than one views run animaiton at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `setAnimationListener` in that you will have following `@override` method

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

}
```

so in that you can show next animation

Comment: I don't want the view appearing one by one. How to make the second view start animation when the first view is still running its animation?